# Dynamic Object Tween

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween

I'm new to Flash/ActionScript 3, I'm trying to dynamically update the Object in a Tween.

The info variable will change depending on what button is pressed.

I'm currently getting the error below...

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at fl.transitions::Tween/setPosition()  at
>   fl.transitions::Tween/set position()  at fl.transitions::Tween()  at
>   Map_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;

var info:MovieClip;

var myTween:Tween = new Tween(info, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 2, true);
myTween.stop();

btn_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

btn_Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick2);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent){
    info = mc_England;
    myTween.start();
}

function onClick2(e:MouseEvent){
    info = mc_Scotland;
    myTween.start();
}
```

Comment: does it error before the buttons are clicked?

Comment: Yep, I get the error before I do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info` is null when you're creating the tween, that's why you're getting a null reference error. Move the instantiation of the tween into your click handlers and you'll be fine.

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent){
    applyTween(mc_England);
}

function onClick2(e:MouseEvent){
    applyTween(mc_Scotland);
}

function applyTween(target:MovieClip){
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(target, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1, 0, 2, true);
    myTween.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did'nt want to repeat the Tween code as I'll be repeating my code many times.